# Finding the maximum value of $t + \frac{1}{t}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Finding the maximum of $t + \frac{1}{t}$ by making the first derivative equal to zero and taking $t=-1$ (because second derivative < 0) gives -2 as the answer. But this is not correct. I guess I am doing some silly (may be conceptual also) mistake somewhere.

Comment: You have a local maximum at $-1$ with value $-2$. That part is correct. For $t > 0$, you have positive values with $\lim_{t\searrow 0} t+\frac1t = +\infty$ and $\lim_{t\to+\infty} t+\frac1t = +\infty$, with a local minimum at $t = 1$. There is no global maximum.

Comment: The function has a local maximum at $t=-1$, but it has no global maximum: it grows without bound as $t\to\infty$. Were you supposed to be looking at it on some closed interval?

Comment: i did some calculation mistake while checking that $-1$ is a local maxima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$t=-1$ is indeed a local maximum. But your function is unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(t)=t+\frac1t\implies f'(t)=1-\frac1{t^2}=0\iff t=\pm 1$$

But we also have

$$f''(t)=\frac2{t^3}\implies f''(-1)<0\implies t=-1\;\;\bf\color{red}{\text{gives a local maximal value}}$$

The importance of **local maximal point** is clear in this case...